# Background image does not adjust on tablet (landscape view)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have experienced this bug/issue with my Homepage background (image) on tablet. 
On laptop screen or bigger screens everything is fine. On mobile devices is fine too. 
But when it comes to load the website from tablet my background looks very strange. 
The image is like centered on the whole Homepage. 
On left, right, top and bottom sides of the image there are showing this empty spaces. In my case they are black.

The tables that I was testing were with following width (in landscape view): 1112px, 1280px.

Here is the CSS for the background:

```
element.style {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(https://test.me/images/bg-image-1-1920x1280.jpg) no- 
    repeat fixed right;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Here is how good my Homepage looks like on laptop screen:
[image: img]

And here is how it looks like on tablet landscape:
[image: img2]

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks

PS - I forgot to mention that on laptop screenshot, the actual image is right adjusted and on left there is black colored background. I mean, the actual image is not on full screen.

Update:
I've tried everything of what you, guys, suggested, but nothing is seems to work like I want (laptop screenshot)

Comment: try `url(https://test.me/images/bg-image-1-1920x1280.jpg) no-repeat fixed right top;` and see if that's the desired result you want.

Comment: can you add your html?

Comment: @Matt-the-Marxist, html is just 

`<div class="page">`

It has also:
`.page {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh!important;
}`

Comment: Can you put it in a snippet

Comment: try to add overflow:hidden;

Comment: @SaqibAmin, my Homepage has second section (after scroll) and with your css, on that second section I get black background. I mean the image ends in the middle of the Homepage and after that there is black background.

Answer (score -1):

I just change `background-position **fixed right**` to `**center center**` and change `background-size: contain` to `background-size: cover`, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.bg {
  background: url(https://images4.alphacoders.com/279/279526.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: Explain what you did.

Comment: @NimitShah I just update the description, I hope the things are more clear now. Thanks

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui, I've tried what you seggested and because my Homepage has second section (I can scroll down), that second section can't be reached. Like the screen is locked on the first part of the Homepage. That's the problem, but otherwise, the first part of the Homepage looks good this way

Comment: can you share the link for more clarification? Thanks

Comment: The screenshot would not help, Have you deployed your code on any server? If yes then please share the link. Thanks

Comment: No, sorry! It's only local, for now.

Comment: Ok, then create any code snippet or fiddle which contain your **HTML, CSS and Scripts**. Thanks